# Relaxing open_basedir error in centos

Tags: php, apache, centos, vesta

I am trying to relax `php_admin_value open_basedir` restriction on the server.

I am using VestaCp on Centos 64 Bit.
I changed the value of `php_admin_value open_basedir` to `none` in `etc/httpd/conf` by writing this line

```
php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

and restrarted my server. but i still have this error in one of my domains

> Warning: realpath(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s):
>
> (/home/admin/web/printskool.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/printskool.com/public_html/system/library/Spout/Common/Helper/FileSystemHelper.php on line 24

Answer (score 0):

Per [this forum entry](https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=6747) you need to edit a different file

Edit `/usr/local/vesta/data/templates/web/httpd/basedir.stpl` and add

```
php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

to this section

```
<Directory %sdocroot%>
```

Note that this will disable it for ALL SITES and could be a security risk

Comment: Its just a temporary need and the variable is set to this value in file -php_admin_value open_basedir %docroot%:%home%/%user%/tmp.

can i restore this value later without any consequences?

Comment: You should be able to. If it's like other CPs, It will overwrite any configurations manually made and you should be able to trigger that reset directly.

Comment: I set it to none and restarted the server, sadly still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything here is how I solved it.

http://arstech.net/fix-error-realpath-open_basedir-restriction-effect/ with reference to this thread.

I don't know how but it worked after nearly 3 hours of searching through the web.